# How to use multiple if-statements once?

Tags: php

Here is my code:

```
if ( $identity == "asker" ) {
    $min_amount = 3000;
} elseif ( $identity == "supporter" ) {
    $min_amount = 5000;
} elseif( $identity == "viewer" ) {
    $min_amount = 7000;
} else {
    throw new Exception('something went wrong');
}

$check_credit = $bounty->check_credit($min_amount);

if ($check_credit["status"] == 1) {

    if ( $identity == "asker" ) {
        $make_bounty_system["content"] = $bounty->make_devote_html($check_credit["amount"], $identity);

    } elseif ( $identity == "supporter" ) {
        $make_bounty_system["content"] = $bounty->make_devote_html($check_credit["amount"], $identity);

    } elseif( $identity == "viewer" ) {
         $make_bounty_system["content"] = $bounty->make_devote_html($check_credit["amount"], $identity);

    } else {
         throw new Exception('something went wrong');
    }
}
```

As you can see, the same logic (`$identity == ?`) is repeated twice. Any idea how can I write the same code cleaner?

Comment: https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10611/141885

Comment: We don't know what `check_credit()` and `make_devote_html()` do/return, so essential aspects of your script cannot be reviewed.  Please edit your question.

Comment: And what should happen if `$check_credit["status"] != 1`?

Answer (score 4):

I think this question goes a bit deeper than just a switch case, but it's not immediately obvious from the way it's worded. What I *think* you're asking is how to avoid doing this both *inside* and *outside* of `if ($check_credit["status"] == 1)`?

> if ( $identity == "asker" )

Put your amounts in an array and reference them as needed.  Also you don't need to repeat the code in the second `if` just check if `$identity` is a key in the array:

```
$amounts = [
        "asker" => 3000,
        "supporter" => 5000,
        "viewer" => 7000
];

if(isset($amounts[$identity])) {
    $check_credit = $bounty->check_credit($amounts[$identity]);
    
    if ($check_credit["status"] == 1) {
        $make_bounty_system["content"] = $bounty->make_devote_html($check_credit["amount"], $identity);
    }
} else {
     throw new Exception('Identity wrong!');
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use [in_array](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php):

```
if (in_array($identity, ["asker", "supporter", "content"])) {
    $make_bounty_system["content"] = $bounty->make_devote_html($check_credit["amount"], $identity);
}
```